# Is this sentence wrong?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

I have read [this article](https://www.vox.com/platform/amp/2018/5/11/17341430/ebola-outbreak-virus-democratic-republic-of-congo) on Vox and there’s this sentence:

> That means Ebola **tends** is deadlier in poorer countries like the DRC than it is in the US or Europe.

First, **tend** is not a noun. Second, if it’s a noun, there has to be **are** because of tend**s**.

So is it wrong?

Comment: You are correct. If you replaced **is** with **to be** after *tends*, the sentence would be correct.

Comment: @RonaldSole I think so.